Calculate Percentage for Progress Bar
I want to implement this progress bar based on array.

Use reduce(), this gives you easy access to the iterator (i) and the complete array (a) on which you're reducing.
Then inside the callback, check the lastMilestoneReached using the previous item's quantity a[i - 1].quantity.
Using that boolean, we can or calculate the read percentage (totalCartItems / c.quantity * 100) or set it to 0. (Using Math.min to ensure we're not showing a percentage above 100)


const discounts = [
  { "discountBasedOn": "QUANTITY", "quantity": 5, "discount": 20 },
  { "discountBasedOn": "QUANTITY", "quantity": 8, "discount": 30 },
  { "discountBasedOn": "QUANTITY", "quantity": 10, "discount": 40 },
];

const totalCartItems = 4;

const res = discounts.reduce((p, c, i, a) => {
    const lastMilestoneReached = (i === 0) || totalCartItems >= a[i - 1].quantity;
    const percentageCompleted = (lastMilestoneReached) ? Math.min((totalCartItems / c.quantity * 100), 100) : 0;
   
    return [ ...p, { ...c, percentageCompleted } ];
}, []);

console.log(res);




this is right. but here i need one more feature.  like see when total cart items 4. first milestone is 80% that means its not completed. so i wanna show others next milestones to 0%. if total cart items 5. that means first milestone si completed second milstone will show 62.5% but third will be show 0% beacuse last one is not completed

I've updated my answer, think this is what you're looking for.
